# VIM highlight current scope

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

Is there a way (or plugin) in vim to highlight current scope.

Say, I am inside function. VIM should use a bright background for the function and dark background for everything else.

When I move inside a loop that is inside the function, only the loop should have the bright background and everything else becomes slightly dark.

Answer (score 1):

junegunn has this very nice plugin that does exactly what you want

https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim

I customized some things to make it better behave the way I'd expect it to:

```
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"MAPPINGS{{{
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
" limelight works on ranges. Declare limelight to bein on content of current line
nnoremap <space>lb :let g:limelight_bop='^'.getline('.').'$'<cr>
" limelight works on ranges. Declare limelight to end on contents of current line
nnoremap <space>le :let g:limelight_eop='^'.getline('.').'$'<cr>
"decrement
nnoremap <space>ld :call SetLimeLightIndent(g:limelightindent - 4)<cr>
"increment
nnoremap <space>li :call SetLimeLightIndent(g:limelightindent + 4)<cr>
"reset indent to default 4
nnoremap <space>lr :call SetLimeLightIndent(4)<cr>
" set limelight toggle
noremap <space>ls :call SetLimeLightIndent(8) 
nnoremap <space>lt :Limelight!!<cr>

"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}}}
"FUNCTIONS{{{
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let g:limelightindent=4
function! LimeLightExtremeties()
    let limelight_start_stop='^\s\{0,'.g:limelightindent.'\}\S'
    let g:limelight_eop=limelight_start_stop
    let g:limelight_bop=limelight_start_stop
    Limelight!!
    Limelight!!
    echo 'limelightindent = '.g:limelightindent
endfunction
function! SetLimeLightIndent(count)
    let g:limelightindent = a:count
    if(g:limelightindent < 0)
        g:limelightindent = 0
    endif
    call LimeLightExtremeties()
endfunction
"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}}}
command! -nargs=*  SetLimeLightIndent call SetLimeLightIndent(<args>)
```